# Unexpected compile error in C++: passing default value to function parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to build a function template, say `util::caller`, to apply elements stored in `std::vector<T>` to a function that accepts those elements as arguments. For example, I have a function `int func(int a, int b, int c)` and a vector of int `std::vector<int> args = {1, 2, 3}`, a function call might be like the following code snippet.

```cpp
int func(int a, int b, int c) {
  return a + b + c;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> args = {1, 2, 3};
  util::caller(func, args);
  return 0;
}
```

The implementation of `util::caller` is almost done, whose signature looks like:

```cpp
template <typename FuncType,
          typename VecType,
          size_t... I,
          typename Traits = function_traits<FuncType>,
          typename ReturnT = typename Traits::result_type>
ReturnT caller(FuncType& func,
                VecType& args,
           indices<I...> placeholder = BuildIndices<Traits::arity>());
```

The definition of stuffs, such as `function_traits` and `BuildIndices`, are in the later part of this post.

---

The compiler reports an unexpected error when I call `func` like `util::caller(func, args)`, but everything is fine when I call `func` like `util::caller(func, args, BuildIndices<3>())`. Please kindly note that in the case of `int func(int, int, int)`, `Traits::arity` equals to `3UL`. That is to say, the two calling of `util::caller` are just the same!

This confused me a lot, and I'm not sure if this is a bug of compiler. (gcc, clang, icc, msvc will all report that unexpected error.) Could anyone explain this? Any clues or hints would be appreciated.

---

MWE could be found at https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/JwHk6_ or:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace util {
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_defs {
  static constexpr size_t arity = sizeof...(Args);

  using result_type = ReturnType;

  template <size_t i>
  struct arg {
    using type = typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
  };
};

template <typename T>
struct function_traits_impl;

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(Args...)>
    : function_traits_defs<ReturnType, Args...> {};

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(*)(Args...)>
    : function_traits_defs<ReturnType, Args...> {};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...)>
    : function_traits_defs<ReturnType, Args...> {};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
    : function_traits_defs<ReturnType, Args...> {};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const&>
    : function_traits_defs<ReturnType, Args...> {};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const&&>
    : function_traits_defs<ReturnType, Args...> {};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) volatile>
    : function_traits_defs<ReturnType, Args...> {};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) volatile&>
    : function_traits_defs<ReturnType, Args...> {};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) volatile&&>
    : function_traits_defs<ReturnType, Args...> {};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const volatile>
    : function_traits_defs<ReturnType, Args...> {};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const volatile&>
    : function_traits_defs<ReturnType, Args...> {};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const volatile&&>
    : function_traits_defs<ReturnType, Args...> {};

template <typename T, typename V = void>
struct function_traits
    : function_traits_impl<T> {};

template <typename T>
struct function_traits<T, decltype((void)&T::operator())>
    : function_traits_impl<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

template <size_t... Indices>
struct indices {
  using next = indices<Indices..., sizeof...(Indices)>;
};
template <size_t N>
struct build_indices {
  using type = typename build_indices<N - 1>::type::next;
};
template <>
struct build_indices<0> {
  using type = indices<>;
};
template <size_t N>
using BuildIndices = typename build_indices<N>::type;

template <typename FuncType,
          typename VecType,
          size_t... I,
          typename Traits = function_traits<FuncType>,
          typename ReturnT = typename Traits::result_type>
ReturnT caller(FuncType& func,
                VecType& args,
           indices<I...> placeholder = BuildIndices<Traits::arity>()) {
  return func(args[I]...);
}

template <typename FuncType>
static constexpr size_t arity(FuncType& func) {
  return function_traits<FuncType>::arity;
}
}  // namespace util

int func(int a, int b, int c) {
  return a + b + c;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> args = {1, 2, 3};

  int j = util::caller(func, args);  // reports error
  // works fine for the following calling
  // int j = util::caller(func, args, util::BuildIndices<3>());
  // int j = util::caller(func, args, util::BuildIndices<util::arity(func)>());
  // int j = util::caller(func, args, util::BuildIndices<util::function_traits<decltype(func)>::arity>());
  std::cout << j << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

---

Compiler error reports:

gcc 9.1:

```
<source>: In function 'ReturnT util::caller(FuncType&, VecType&, util::indices<I ...>) [with FuncType = int(int, int, int); VecType = std::vector<int>; long unsigned int ...I = {}; Traits = util::function_traits<int(int, int, int), void>; ReturnT = int]':

<source>:116:34: error: could not convert 'util::BuildIndices<3>()' from 'indices<#'nontype_argument_pack' not supported by dump_expr#<expression error>>' to 'indices<#'nontype_argument_pack' not supported by dump_expr#<expression error>>'

  116 |   int j = util::caller(func, args);  // reports error

      |                                  ^

      |                                  |

      |                                  indices<#'nontype_argument_pack' not supported by dump_expr#<expression error>>

<source>:116:34: note:   when instantiating default argument for call to 'ReturnT util::caller(FuncType&, VecType&, util::indices<I ...>) [with FuncType = int(int, int, int); VecType = std::vector<int>; long unsigned int ...I = {}; Traits = util::function_traits<int(int, int, int), void>; ReturnT = int]'

<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:116:34: error: could not convert 'util::BuildIndices<3>()' from 'indices<#'nontype_argument_pack' not supported by dump_expr#<expression error>>' to 'indices<#'nontype_argument_pack' not supported by dump_expr#<expression error>>'

Compiler returned: 1
```

clang 8.0.0:

```
<source>:99:26: error: no viable conversion from 'indices<0UL aka 0, 1UL aka 1, sizeof...(Indices) aka 2>' to 'indices<(no argument), (no argument), (no argument)>'

           indices<I...> placeholder = BuildIndices<Traits::arity>()) {

                         ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

<source>:116:11: note: in instantiation of default function argument expression for 'caller<int (int, int, int), std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, util::function_traits<int (int, int, int), void>, int>' required here

  int j = util::caller(func, args);  // reports error

          ^

<source>:78:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'BuildIndices<function_traits<int (int, int, int), void>::arity>' (aka 'indices<0UL, 1UL, sizeof...(Indices)>') to 'const util::indices<> &' for 1st argument

struct indices {

       ^

<source>:78:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'BuildIndices<function_traits<int (int, int, int), void>::arity>' (aka 'indices<0UL, 1UL, sizeof...(Indices)>') to 'util::indices<> &&' for 1st argument

struct indices {

       ^

<source>:99:26: note: passing argument to parameter 'placeholder' here

           indices<I...> placeholder = BuildIndices<Traits::arity>()) {

                         ^

<source>:100:25: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 0

  return func(args[I]...);

         ~~~~           ^

<source>:116:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'util::caller<int (int, int, int), std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, util::function_traits<int (int, int, int), void>, int>' requested here

  int = util::caller(func, args);  // reports error

                ^

2 errors generated.

Compiler returned: 1
```

icc 19.0.1:

```
<source>(99): error: no suitable user-defined conversion from "util::BuildIndices<3UL>" to "util::indices<>" exists

             indices<I...> placeholder = BuildIndices<Traits::arity>()) {

                                         ^

          detected during instantiation of "ReturnT util::caller(FuncType &, VecType &, util::indices<I...>) [with FuncType=int (int, int, int), VecType=std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>, I=<>, Traits=util::function_traits<int (int, int, int), void>, ReturnT=int]" at line 116

<source>(100): error #165: too few arguments in function call

    return func(args[I]...);

                          ^

          detected during instantiation of "ReturnT util::caller(FuncType &, VecType &, util::indices<I...>) [with FuncType=int (int, int, int), VecType=std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>, I=<>, Traits=util::function_traits<int (int, int, int), void>, ReturnT=int]" at line 116

compilation aborted for <source> (code 2)

Compiler returned: 2
```

msvc 19.21:

```
example.cpp

<source>(99): error C2440: 'default argument': cannot convert from 'util::indices<0,1,2>' to 'util::indices<>'

<source>(99): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Compiler returned: 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is not a bug. The compiler is not deducing `I` as you expected because it is not supposed to deduce template parameters based on default arguments, as mentioned in case (4) of the non-deduced contexts on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

That said, it is not hard to make your code work as you expected, as long as you manually overload `caller` (instead of using a default argument).

```cpp
template <typename FuncType,
          typename VecType,
          size_t... I,
          typename Traits = function_traits<FuncType>,
          typename ReturnT = typename Traits::result_type>
ReturnT caller(FuncType& func,
                VecType& args,
           indices<I...> placeholder) {
  return func(args[I]...);
}

template <typename FuncType, typename VecType>
typename function_traits<FuncType>::result_type caller(
    FuncType& func, VecType& args) {
  return caller(func, args, BuildIndices<function_traits<FuncType>::arity>());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Blaok, that's the point. Thanks for your carefully reading of cppreference and the answer. Yes, just after I noticed the problem posted in the question, I figured out this workaround. Hence accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Think about this being called with two arguments:

```
template <typename FuncType,
          typename VecType,
          size_t... I,
          typename Traits = function_traits<FuncType>,
          typename ReturnT = typename Traits::result_type>
ReturnT caller(FuncType& func,
               VecType& args,
               indices<I...> placeholder = BuildIndices<Traits::arity>());
```

There are basically two ways for that. One way explicitly specifies the template parameters (at least the first three). The other way, which you use, leaves determining the template parameters to the compiler. The compiler does that from the given arguments. For the first two parameters, it's easy, they match exactly the given arguments. However, for the third template parameter, that doesn't work because that one depends on the third argument which in turn depends on the third template parameter.

Suggestion: Can't you use `Traits::arity` in place of `I`?

Notes:

- The all uppercase `I` name formally matches what is typically reserved to macro names.
- Yes, the compiler message all suck.

Comment: Thanks Ulrich. All `I` here will be replaced to `Idx` later. I'm not quite understand why compiler could not determine the third template parameter. It could be determined in the following path: 1. determining `FuncType` to be `int(*)(int, int, int)`; 2. determining `Traits` to be `function_traits<FuncType>`; 3. deducing `BuildIndices<Traits::arity>` to be `indices<0, 1, 2>`; 4. based on the third function parameter, determining the parameter pack to be `0, 1, 2`, which is the third parameter in template.

Comment: Also, I'm not quite understand your words: use `Traits::arity` in place of `I`. How to do this?

Comment: I could easily be wrong, that much up front. I do think that your reasoning has a flaw though: The default value for the third function argument is defined indirectly. However, I doubt that this implies the type of this argument. One thing I'd try is to code the third function parameter as template parameter, just like the first two.

Comment: Concerning the `Traits::arity` in place of `I`, I believe both are integers and they both have the same value. Don't they?

Comment: No... `I` is a parameter pack here, while `Traits::arity` is an `unsigned long int`. They are not the same thing.

Comment: Oh, missed that part, I'm not that familiar with post C++11 features. But then it's pretty clear: Since you only provide two arguments, `I...` becomes an empty parameter pack while the default argument value depends on the arity of the function. Those two don't match, which is exactly what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: Yes, that's what compilers complained about. But the point is that, when passing `BuildIndices<function_traits<decltype(func)>::arity>()` to the caller as its third argument, everything works fine. It's the same thine when compare to `BuildIndices<Traits::arity>()`. I doubt if it's because that the deduction path for `size_t... I` is too long for compilers (they are not that smart enough to deduce), hence the term 'bug' is used in the question description.